# App Script formula in Google spreadsheet cell gets invalidated and needs forced reload

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm managing a student registration system based on Google docs. Students enter their registration data in a Google Form, the results are gathered in a Google spreadsheet ("Préinscriptions") that uses additional sheets to normalize the data. The data is then imported by another spreadsheet ("Inscriptions") to handle the registrations.

In two normalization sheets in the Google spreadsheet, I use custom Apps Script functions to normalize the data from the response sheets. The functions are used in a vertical concatenation array to gather normalized data from several response sheets into the normalization sheets. The formulas look like this:

On tab "Nouveaux":

```
={normalizeNouveau("FR", 'FR - Nouveau'!$A$1:$AB);normalizeNouveau("EN", 'EN - Nouveau'!$A$1:$AB); normalizeNouveau("ES", 'ES - Nouveau'!$A$1:$AB)}
```

On tab "Anciens":

```
={normalizeAncien("FR", 'FR - Ancien'!$A$1:$AB); normalizeAncien("EN", 'EN - Ancien'!$A$1:$AB); normalizeAncien("ES", 'ES - Ancien'!$A$1:$AB)}
```

`normalizeNouveau` and `normalizeAncien` are the custom functions that normlized data linewise. "FR - Nouveau", "EN - Nouveau" ... "ES - Ancien" are the response sheets.

Now the problem is that, while this all globally works great, the formulas that gather the normalized data, on both "Anciens" and "Nouveaux" sheets, sometimes get "disconnected" (for lack of a better word) and display error messages for each formula -- either a single one or 3, corresponding I expect to the three blocks of data produced by the various function calls. When that happens (usually several times a day), what I need to do is (simply :-| ) to cut the formulas from their original cells, validate the change, then paste them again. And then the data reappears normally.

When the problem happens:

[image: problem on "Nouveaux" tab]

[image: problem on "Anciens" tab]

After cut-pasting:

[image: normal contents on "Nouveaux" tab]

That is very problematic because, as I said, another file ("Inscriptions") uses that data to handle many aspects of the registration process, and when this happens, that whole files becomes empty and useless -- this can even lead to errors if the problem occurs at a time where I'm running an Apps Script function, because the data is then effectively absent. So when that happens in "Inscriptions", I need to go back to "Préinscriptions" to perform the little trick I was just describing. Doing it myself is annoying enough, but other people might need to use that file too and would simply get stuck or, worse, break something if the data simply disappears without warning.

Sometimes the connection seems to break between "Préinscriptions" and "Inscriptions", which loads the data from yet a third tab where "Nouveaux" and "Anciens" get merged. The same trick applies, although it may need several attempts to successfully show the data:

[image: tab in "Inscriptions" file]

Can anyone tell me why this happen and if there's anything I can do to prevent it? I'm heavily relying on the stable dataflow between the forms, response sheets and registration spreadsheet for the system to work, and this is just breaking the workflow way too often to be negligible.

Comment: Could you paste the code for normalizeNouveau() and provide a sample spreadsheet?

Comment: @NikkoJ. I honestly don't think the code is relevant here, since the synchronization issues are not connected to data changes -- so the function produces lines as expected (returning 2-dimensional arrays of constant width and relevant height). I'll try and find time to generate a sample spreadsheet but I'm not sure how the connection to several forms (6 in total) may have an impact -- and I obviously can't share these sheets that contain personal data.

Comment: Apologies but it is difficult on my end to debug your issue without the function and sample data (dummy data). Try to replicate your issue to a dummy spreadsheet and share it with us so we can have a better view to the problem. Also see [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)